# Most efficient way to query for multiple rows and their specific sub-items (e.g. A `Sale` table and its `Items`)

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have the following tables:

Sales Table:

```
+----+------------+
| ID |    Date    |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 11/20/2018 |
|  2 | 11/21/2018 |
+----+------------+
```

Items Table:

```
+----+------------+----------+-------+----------+
| ID | FK_Sale_ID | Quantity | Price | Subtotal |
+----+------------+----------+-------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |        5 |   100 |      500 |
|  2 |          1 |        3 |    50 |      150 |
|  3 |          2 |        5 |    60 |      300 |
+----+------------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Currently, I query for the `Sale` rows and then run another query for each to retrieve all of its `Items` after which, I initialize them as objects in my C# Program. My problem is that I frequently run into scenarios where I'm dealing with hundreds of sales at the same time. Because of this, I have to run hundreds of queries as well.

My question is, is there a more efficient way to query for all `Sales` and their `Items` or is this it? I thought of trying a query like

```
SELECT *
FROM items_table
WHERE FK_Sale_ID = '1' OR FK_Sale_ID = '2'
```

And then manually sorting which Item belonged to which sale for initialization but this query quickly got messy after dealing with more than a few sales. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not `join` the tables in query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [join clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to combine multiple tables data in your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM items_table 
JOIN sales_table ON items_table.FK_Sale_ID = sales_table.ID
WHERE sales_table.Date = @somedate
```

With this query when `@somedate = 11/20/2018` you basically will get this data in one go:

```
+----+------------+----+------------+----------+-------+----------+
| ID |    Date    | ID | FK_Sale_ID | Quantity | Price | Subtotal |
+----+------------+----+------------+----------+-------+----------+
|  1 | 11/20/2018 |  1 |          1 |        5 |   100 |      500 |
|  1 | 11/20/2018 |  2 |          1 |        3 |    50 |      150 |
+----+------------+----+------------+----------+-------+----------+
```

Use `SELECT items_table.*` to get all fields of items table only